# iCal Sync with Google Apps Other Calendar

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

Our companies email/calendering is run through Google Apps and we all share everyone elses under "Other calendars" within the web interface of Google Cal. So my calendar syncs fine and has no issues with iCal, but invitations/alerts/reminders from the shared calendars show pending actions for each one. I can click on all the normal options "Maybe" "Decline" "Accept" but they just come back as I have read only access to them.

Things I have checked:
1.) In Google Calendar - they are all set to not receive notifications for anything.
2.) In iCal I have checked each calendars settings and "Ignore alerts" is checked for each calendar. 
3.) In iCal I have checked the Alerts settings for my account and everything is set to None.

So even though i've checked those I have currently got 40+ pending Notifications pending action.

Has anyone had this before and found a solution?

Thanks in advance and my apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: I have this problem to and this is very annoying... did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: I did not - I ended up stopping using iCal as it became to unmanageable. I switched to Outlook Calendar which works nicely.

Comment: I opened a bug and I’m exchanging with apple engineers right now to try to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by going to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect and unchecking my teammate calendar from the sync.

This is not totally fine because I cannot see my teammate calendar from *Calendar* but at least I can use it for my different pro and personnal calendars without being bugged by notification when my teammate are invited to an event.